# Tomcat SSL exclude URL pattern

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, ssl, java-ee-6

I have a web application which hosts the web-app itself and a REST endpoint.

The web-application is using SSL for every resource. However, i would like to use plain HTTP for accessing the REST endpoint, without having to supply a certificate. Reason being, the REST endpoint is accesed by a service which does not have a certificate.

I tried to set two different security constraints in my web.xml but this didn't help. Even though i access the REST endpoint, the protocol turns to HTTPS automatically.

My config looks like below:

```
<!-- For the REST Endpoint -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Rest_Endpoint</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/restEndpoint/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- The  security constraint -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>certificate required</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>web_application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern><!-- Every URI will be under certificate protection -->
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Allowed roles for this security constraint</description>
        <role-name>test_role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>SSL required</description>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Am I missing something here? Do you know how can some web resources (e.g. the rest endpoint URLs) use HTTP when accessing them, but in the meantime the rest of the web-app uses HTTPS ?

I have searched around and people are suggesting a custom Filter. Is this my only solution or can i succeed what i want by configuration ?

Thank you.

P.S: I am using Tomcat 7 as an application server

Comment: I guess that the second constraint overrules the first one (because of `/*`). Did you try to swap the two constraints (Certificate Required first)?

Comment: Btw: I do not understand the reason for that, each and every service  consumer should be able to handle TLS/SSL.

Comment: Hi @home thanks for your response. No i haven't tried switching the two, as i read that the more specific one should be first. Let me try that and come back to you. Indeed the reason is strange, but the service accessing the rest endpoint is running under a system account (ie automated process) and does not have a certificate at the moment. Thus the REST service gives back an error.

Comment: So, it did work by swapping? For me, it didnt work. Just curious to know how you fixed this?